# Customizing doc theme build on readthedocs site

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

ReadTheDocs.org is a really great way to post sphinx-generated html, but there are a few minor theme-related issues that I would prefer to have handled differently. After reading through a bunch of pages here, I am not sure if they can be addressed for docs hosted on RTFD.org or only for local builds using the ReadTheDocs theme.

The items I prefer from my local default build are the following:

- the RTFD puts all text in tables onto a single line and uses a scroll bar. Cool for narrow tables, but not the way I use them. I would greatly prefer text wrapping.
- the sphinx-generated index is a really nice tool for people writing code (which is who these docs are to help). It is in the PDF, but on-line would be more useful.
- the index of modules is also nice feature I'd like to get back, though way less valuable than the previous index.

Are these even possible to change? If so, what goes in my conf.py?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the [docs for the theme](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Have you looked at the [repo for the project and its issue tracker](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme)? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I spent quite some time reading the sphinx_rtd_theme docs before posting, but they seemed to relate to installing and customizing the theme for local use, not how to customize on ReadTheDocs.org, beyond the listed config options.

Comment: You can fork and customize the theme, release it as a package on PyPI, and install it as a custom theme. I did that for docs under the Pylons Project, using [pylons-sphinx-themes](https://github.com/pylons/pylons-sphinx-themes).